# Share Android Studio Prefs with team members

Tags: android-studio

How can I share for example Live Templates, Format Style, Clean Style with other team members using android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export Settings from one machine as JAR archive and import the same in other team members machines

Wondering how to do that here is the reference guide :

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/exporting-and-importing-settings.html